# Entity Framework - Distinct on 2 columns but get back all data

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've got a really complicated Entity Framework problem and I haven't got a clue how to write my query in SQL or EF.

My table is something like this:

```
RecordId - int
ListId - int
ScreenName - string
Name - string
Description - string
Community - string
Value1 - decimal
Value2 - decimal
Value3 - decimal
```

I want to search this table and I need the results to be distinct based on a combination of ScreenName and Community. In other words, if there are multiple records with the same ScreenName and Community, I only want one row back. If there are multiple records with the same ScreenName and two different communities, then I will should get 2 records.

I want the full row, not just the ScreenName and Community.

When grouping records, if I could select which record to keep based on the ListId (lower is better), that would be ideal.

Is it possible to do any of what I've asked in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and a lot of time getting frustrated with SQL Server, I finally figured it out

SQL

```
select * from ListRecord lr
where ListRecordId = 
(
    select top 1 ListRecordId
    from ListRecord
    where ScreenName = lr.ScreenName
    and Community = lr.Community
    order by ListId
)
```

Entity Framework

```
var query = from x in db.ListRecords
            where x.ListRecordId == (
                db.ListRecords.Where(y => y.ScreenName == x.ScreenName && y.Community == x.Community)
                .OrderBy(y => y.ListId)
                .Select(y => y.ListRecordId).FirstOrDefault()
                )
            select x;

var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Great Owen! I got stuck with the same thing, but your answer is brilliant! 
Thank you very much!